# Outlook Focused Inbox: show unread only

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-online

I'm really trying to like the "Focused Inbox" feature of Outlook with Exchange Online.
However, I miss a view showing me only the "unread" items in the focused inbox.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Its possible to set it to Focussed Inbox, and then apply a filter that it only shows unread mails. The downside of this is that you have to specifically remove the filter again if you want to go back to all mails. Is that acceptable, or do you want the ability to switch by a button press?

Comment: LPChip: clever thinking. I think if you post that as an answer, I'll have to upvote and accept it, even if it's a clumsy way - but it appears to be the only way!

Comment: There's an answer now that shows it. Won't make a duplicate and I don't really need the reputation either. Feel free to accept that one.

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested you select "Unread Mail" in the built-in filter, show as the screenshot:
[image]